# Is there any property of tab in tabBar to change the text color of tab in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am including tabs in my app using flutter. My tab background color is white. May be the by default color of tab text is white. How can I change the text color of tab?

```
 bottom: TabBar(
               tabs: <Widget>[
                      Tab(text: "Maintenance"),
                      Tab(text: "Repair"),
                    ],
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `labelColor` property of `TabBar` :

```
     bottom: TabBar(
           tabs: <Widget>[
                  Tab(text: "Maintenance"),
                  Tab(text: "Repair"),
                ],
           labelColor: Colors.black,
     )
```